# Pandas TypeError: aggregate() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, pandas

This works fine on windows. What I am trying to do is:

```
dates = data.agg(no_days=("date", "size"))
```

i.e. use the .agg function to sum up the number of times each date appears in the column.

This works fine on Windows, but when I ssh into my university's unix system, it produces the error:

```
TypeError: aggregate() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

pandas version 0.24.2, python version 2.7

how can I fix this?

Comment: what version of python and what version of pandas are installed

Comment: i've edited it, on reflection clearly the problem is the python version, but i'll leave the question up in case someone actually intends to use python 2.7 and gets this error, thanks

Comment: It's really the pandas version. But with `python 2.7` you can't go any higher than `pandas 0.24.2` and named aggregations were't introduced until `0.25.0`